# Existence of maxima for function on a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, banach-spaces

I remember doing these kind of exercises so easily while following a basic Functional Analysis course but after years I'm stuck and I would really need some help.$$\quad$$
Let $(B,|\cdot|)$ be a Banach space and $h:B\to\mathbb{R}$ a non-negative function with compact sublevels, namely $\forall r\in[0,\infty)$ the set $\{x\in B: h(x)\leq r\}$ is compact in $B$ (clearly, as all compact sets are closed in a metric space, this implies in particular that $h$ is lower semicontinous) and such that $$\frac{h(x)}{|x|}\to\infty\quad\text{uniformly as}\quad |x|\to\infty.$$
Let now $\phi:B\to\mathbb{R}$ be another function such that there exist $C,D>0$ for which $\phi(x)\leq C+D|x|$. $$\qquad$$
I need to prove that $\sup\limits_{x\in B} \{\phi(x)-h(x)\}$ is attained in $B$.$$\qquad$$
This seems super easy to my intuition but... well, as I said, cannot prove it! Thanks to anyone that will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sketch of a proof/plan-of-attack.
$$ \sup_{x \in B: |x| \geq n}\{ \phi(x) - h(x)\} \leq \sup_{x \in B: |x| \geq n}\{ C + D|x| - h(x)\} \rightarrow_n - \infty$$
by the uniform growth condition. So, it suffices to consider only $x$ with $|x| \leq M$ for some $M$ large enough. Define $r = \sup_{x \in B: |x| \leq M}\{ \phi(x) - h(x)\} $ which is upper bounded. I claim $r$ is also lower bounded but this needs to be shown. It suffices to consider only $x$ with $h(x) \leq  \sup_{x \in B: |x| \leq M} \phi(x) + |r|$. Note $\delta:= \sup_{x \in B: |x| \leq M} \phi(x) + |r|\leq C + DM + |r| < \infty$ is finite. Therefore, it suffices to consider the maximization problem:
$$\sup_{x:h(x) \leq \delta}\{ \phi(x) - h(x)\}$$
where the supremum is now over a compact set by the property of $h$. Since the set is compact, the maximum is attained (I think this follows from lower semicontinuity).

I am actually not entirely confident that $r$ is lower bounded, which this proof depends on.